# DISTINCT com UNION e COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou realizando uma consulta no banco de dados para retornar 6 resultados de um tabela `Agenda` que tem vários horários disponíveis por dia (ex: *08:10:00:000 | 08:30:00:000*) e por períodos (ex: `T` (representando 'tardes' ou `M` representando 'manhãs').

Estou conseguindo recuperar já, mas tenho um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Só posso ter um horário para cada período do dia.

Ex: posso ter no dia *19/12/2015* um horário no período da manhã e um horário no período da tarde, mas **nunca** posso ter no dia *19/12/2015* dois horários no período da manhã ou da tarde.

A minha query está assim:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'M' AS periodo
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador, 
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) < 12 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'T' AS periodo  
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE()
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador,
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) >= 12 
    AND 
        COUNT(CAST(agendadata AS DATE)) = 1 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) B
GROUP BY 
    agendaidentificador, 
    agendadata,
    periodo
HAVING 
    COUNT(CAST(agendadata as DATE)) = 1
ORDER BY agendadata
```

e o resultado é:

```
linha |agendaIdentificador |             agendaData  | periodo
------|--------------------|-------------------------|---------
  1   |             173352 | 2015-01-12 12:50:00.000 |  T
  2   |             173363 | 2015-01-12 14:40:00.000 |  T
  3   |             175255 | 2015-01-19 11:30:00.000 |  M
  4   |             175520 | 2015-01-26 14:50:00.000 |  T
  5   |             125074 | 2015-02-25 08:20:00.000 |  M
  6   |             125076 | 2015-02-25 08:40:00.000 |  M
```

E não pode acontecer como aconteceu nas linhas `1` e `2`.

E eu estou travado nisso e não consegui ainda achar uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No [SOEN (Link para a resposta)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27151549/3433145) resolveram o meu problema (precisei de umas modificações para me atenden, mas ficou bala.

Utilizando duas `CTE - Common Table Expression` e `OVER PARTITION BY`

```
WITH CTE_AGENDA AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE), periodo ORDER BY agendaData) RN
    FROM AGENDA
)
,CTE_AGENDA2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(agendaData AS DATE), CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,AGENDADATA) < 12 THEN 'M' ELSE 'T' END  ORDER BY newid(),agendaData desc) RN2
    FROM AGENDA
)
```

E a consulta ficou:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'M' AS periodo
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE 
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador, 
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) < 12 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) agendaidentificador,agendadata, 'T' AS periodo  
    FROM AGENDA
    WHERE     
        agendaconsumolocktempo IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendaconsumoidentificador IS NULL 
    AND 
        agendadata > GETDATE()
        and RN2 = 1
    GROUP BY 
        agendaidentificador,
        agendadata
    HAVING 
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,agendadata) AS INT) >= 12 
    AND 
        COUNT(CAST(agendadata AS DATE)) = 1 
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        agendadata asc
) B
GROUP BY 
    agendaidentificador, 
    agendadata,
    periodo
HAVING 
    COUNT(CAST(agendadata as DATE)) = 1
ORDER BY agendadata
```

Comment: Então fecha o tópico e da como respondida a questão

Comment: Como fechar o tópico e dar como respondida?

Comment: Seleciona o certo embaixo da tua resposta, ou aqui não funciona isso?

Comment: Aqui só depois de 2 dias eu posso fazer isso